# Create a table in a new database with data from another table from another database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Express 2008 that is installed with Visual Studio 2010. I need to copy an old table (with some or all of its columns) to another table in a new database.

Please note that I have installed SQL Server Express Edition on the client side so I don't want to use the Management Studio to do so.

So far I have tried

```
INSERT INTO trying.new_table SELECT * from msp.old_table
```

> where **trying** and **msp** are the two databases respectively.

All I get is "Invalid Object Name 'msp.old_table'" Error!

Also please note that I have attached the "msp" database into Visual Studio using the Add Connection Wizard.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to add table `schema` before table name, if its `dbo`, try this:

```
INSERT INTO [trying].dbo.new_table SELECT * from [msp].dbo.old_table
```

Comment: are they in same server ?

Comment: maybe its express versions limitation, i dont know exactly, but the syntax is correct, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: I am running SQL Server Express Edition. One database is attached (an mdf file) while the other is newly created.